# Import drawSvg in python file throws errors

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm trying to use the drawSvg library in python but it throws these errors when I try to run my file :

```
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\project>python pr.py
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\drawSvg\raster.py:18: RuntimeWarning: Fail
ed to import CairoSVG. drawSvg will be unable to output PNG or other raster image formats. See https
://github.com/cduck/drawSvg#prerequisites for more details.
Original OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

I already installed drawSvg and cairoSvg

```
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\project>python -m pip list
Package      Version
------------ ---------
cairocffi    1.3.0
CairoSVG     2.5.2
certifi      2021.10.8
cffi         1.15.0
click        8.0.3
colorama     0.4.4
cssselect2   0.4.1
defusedxml   0.7.1
drawSvg      1.8.3
Flask        2.0.2
imageio      2.12.0
itsdangerous 2.0.1
Jinja2       3.0.2
MarkupSafe   2.0.1
numpy        1.21.4
Pillow       8.4.0
pip          21.3.1
pycparser    2.21
setuptools   59.3.0
svgwrite     1.4.1
tinycss2     1.1.1
webencodings 0.5.1
Werkzeug     2.0.2
wheel        0.37.0
wincertstore 0.2
```

In my file i simply did

> import drawSvg as draw

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution but unfortunately there is none, especially for us Windows users, but for Lunix users they can check this  [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/drawSvg/#description)

I found out that you can actually still use drawSvg to generate an svg file even if you get this errors but of course you can't generate images because the problem here is related to cairoSvg I tried to install [Glade](https://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/) which is said to solve the problem but nothing happened.